# Having trouble with git filter-branch, "ambiguous argument"

Tags: git

I have a git tree:

- `egit/`

  - `project1/`
  - `project2/`

And I am trying to split `project1` off to another repository. So I open command-prompt and `cd` into the `egit` folder. Then, following [this tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/), I run the command `git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter \ project1\ master`. I keep getting the error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'project1\': unknown revision or path not in the
working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

I have verified that `project1` is in my git repo using `git ls-tree --full-tree -r HEAD`, so I have no idea what is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using backslashes?

Comment: err command prompt uses backslashes? I always get confused, so if forward slashes are the way to go, I'll change my ways. Changing to forward slashes in this case still gives the same error tho :/

Comment: So your command now is `git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter project1/ master`, correct? (in the github example the backslash is escaping a newline, it isn't needed.) In any case, you can drop the trailing slash

Comment: ok I didn't know that, that's a little embarrassing. I thought it was a reference to the root directory or something, my bad. works now lol

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command.

`git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter project1 master`

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, but here's what I found running git-bash on Windows. If the remote repository is checked out on a branch, then this format will give the error:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter project1 master
```

However, if you go to the remote repository, which in my case was another folder, and `git checkout master`, then the filter-branch runs without error.

Also, if the remote repo is checked out on a branch, this format will run without error, and use the same branch for the new repo:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter project1
```